# Victory Chart issues with spacing between axis and tickValues

Tags: reactjs, victory-charts

This is the type of chart I want in my project[image: stacked column chart]

The chart is taken from the tutorial of [Victory Chart](http://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/) and the code for the same can be found [here](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory-tutorial/blob/9bf170061599027e4bd5fcf8128e47adb83c0e98/src/js/client.js)

Now I want the chart with the similar structure and so I tried to adapt the example code to represent the data I want but Instead I get this:

[image]

As You can see the spaces between the tick values in the x-axis are completely jumbled up and the code for the same:

```js
<VictoryChart
            theme={VictoryTheme.material}
            domain={{ y: [0, 50] }}
            domainPadding={130}
        >
            
            <VictoryAxis
                //padding={{ left: 50, right: 50  }}
                tickValues={date}
                tickFormat={ (t, i) => { return t + ' '+ month[i]} }   
            />

             <VictoryAxis
               dependentAxis
            />
 
            <VictoryStack
                colorScale={this.state.colors}>
               
            </VictoryStack> 
        </VictoryChart>
```

So My question is How do I create **spacing between** the *tick values* in the **x-axis.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `fixLabelOverlap` prop like so:

```
<VictoryAxis
 tickValues={date}
 tickFormat={ (t, i) => { return t + ' '+ month[i]} }
 fixLabelOverlap 
/>
```

Or you can use the `angle` style value to place your labels vertically

```
<VictoryAxis
 tickValues={date}
 tickFormat={ (t, i) => { return t + ' '+ month[i]} }
 style={{tickLabels: { angle: 90 }}}
/>
```